# SQL Take off last character if a certain one exists in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a column with few different `ID`'s

```
abc_1234
abc_2345
bcd_3456/
cde_4567/
```

And I want a new column that takes off the `/` if it exists

```
abc_1234
abc_2345
bcd_3456
cde_4567
```

I know I'll be using a combination of IF/THEN, `LEFT`, and `LEN`, but I don't know the syntax. Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms? String handling may differ depending on product...

Comment: What if // at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*In case your are using SQL Server RDBMS*)

You can try the following combination of `right` and `left`:

```
case when right(col, 1) = '/' then left(col, len(col)-1) else col end
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/855d2/1)

(*In case your are using MySQL RDBMS*)

```
trim(trailing '/' from col);
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/469d4e/4)

Comment: this wouldn't take into account if there was more then one '/'

Answer (score 2):

If your using SQL Server try this

```
SELECT REPLACE(col,'/','')
```

[Replace (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You would usually simply trim the string:

- Oracle: `select rtrim(col, '/') from ...`
- MySQL and PostgreSQL: `select trim(trailing '/' from col) from ...`

but not all DBMS offer this. SQL Server for instance doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLServer

```
declare @tbl table
(
    c1 nvarchar(9)
)
insert into @tbl values ('abc_1234')
insert into @tbl values ('abc_2345')
insert into @tbl values ('abc_3456/')
insert into @tbl values ('abc_4567/')

select  IIF(RIGHT(c1, 1) = '/', LEFT(C1, LEN(C1)-1), C1)
from    @tbl
```

**Result**
abc_1234
abc_2345
abc_3456
abc_4567